# Rundeck ACL Limit user to only see specific groups in project

Tags: acl, rundeck

Is it possible in Rundeck to limit a user group to only see a specific group inside of a project.  The project has 5 different groups "folders" with jobs in there.  I can limit run access to the group I want, but I don't want the user group to see any of the other folders under the project. Does that make sense?

Project

- group1  Hide for a user group
- group2  Access for all
- group3  Hide for a user group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is.

Just remove `read` from the job group acl.

The follow acl only allow user from user_group to run and read jobs under group2 only. The users can not read(see) jobs other than jobs under group2

```
description: Limited user access for group in a project
context:
  project: 'project1'
for:
  job:
    - equals:
        group: 'group2'
      allow: [run,read]
by:
  group: [user_group]
```

Note: if you have multiple acl, your acl may be overridden by another acl file.

[Rundeck ACL](http://rundeck.org/2.7.3/administration/access-control-policy.html#application-scope-resources-and-actions)

Comment: Thanks. That did it. The ACL docs are a bit confusing but this will help immensely. Thanks.